# How to retrieve row from a html table on mouse click in PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am displaying some records in an HTML table using PHP. I am trying to make it so that when I click on a row, I can store the **itemID** (that has been clicked on) in a variable. For some reason, when I click on the row I want, the alert in JavaScript just doesn't work nor does it happen. Am I missing something trivial?

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","mypassword","myDB");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    echo "<font color = 'darkgreen'> Connected to database. </font> <br>";

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Inventory");

    echo "<table border='1'>
    <tr>
    <th>Item ID</th>
    <th>Item Name</th>
    </tr>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['itemID'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['itemName'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";

    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $("tr.table").click(function() {
        var tableData = $(this).children("td").map(function() {
            return $(this).text();
        }).get();

        alert("Your data is: " + $.trim(tableData[0]) + " , " + $.trim(tableData[1]));
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: As I see, you're calling the jQuery click on a <tr></tr> with the class "table", but I don't see where you set that class in your <tr></tr>

Comment: How can I do that exactly? I'm not too familiar with html

Comment: <tr class="table">
    <th>Item ID</th>
    <th>Item Name</th>
</tr>

Just add the class to the table, but you still gonna need to tell JS you want ONLY this <tr> itemID and not all <tr> in your code.

Comment: Remove the in PHP part of the title. Looks like you'll be using JavaScript, since this is Event based... unless, of course, you want database info... then you sill send and receive info to the Server with JavaScript, using PHP with MySQL to access data and `echo json_encode($assocArray)`. Oh, the font tag is dead. Just advice. The comments by `@Alberto Rubio` are what you need to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","mypassword","myDB");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    echo "<h3 style='color: darkgreen;'> Connected to database. </h3> <br />";

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Inventory");

    echo "<table border='1'>
    <tr>
    <th>Item ID</th>
    <th>Item Name</th>
    </tr>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td class='item-id'>" . $row['itemID'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td class='item-name'>" . $row['itemName'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";

    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $("tr").click(function() {

        var id = $(this).find('.item-id').text();
        var name = $(this).find('.item-name').text();

        alert("Your data is: " + $.trim(id) + " , " + $.trim(name));
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<tr onclick='showAlert($row['itemID'],$row['itemName']);'>";
```

please write in your table and create java script function to show alert

```
<script>
     function showAlert(TxtItemid,txtItemName){
      alert("Your data is: " + TxtItemid + " , " + txtItemName));
     }
</script>
```

this is one of the way to alert.Please have try on this. This will work for you. It is working in my case.